# Flask, NoForeignKeysError despite model table correctly set unless otherwise

Tags: flask, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

I thought I correctly define my data models where i want to link Community with their agenda however I am having the following error.
Can you please give a hint?

> NoForeignKeysError: Could not determine join condition between parent/child tables on relationship CSCommunity.agenda - there are no foreign keys linking these tables.  Ensure that referencing columns are associated with a ForeignKey or ForeignKeyConstraint, or specify a 'primaryjoin' expression.

on the following code.

```
class Agenda(db.Model):
__tablename__ = 'communityagenda'
id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
csc = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('scorecards.id'))
cscommunity = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('cscommunities.id'))
meeting_date = db.Column(db.DateTime)
notes = db.Column(db.Text)

class CSCommunity(db.Model):
__tablename = 'cscommunities'
id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
name = db.Column(db.String(150))
key_leaders = db.Column(db.Text)
subgroup = db.Column(db.Text)
#---------------------------
region = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('regions.id'))
district  = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('districts.id'))
subdistrict  = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('subdistricts.id'))
village = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('villages.id'))
agenda = db.relationship('Agenda', backref='cscommunity', cascade='all, delete-orphan', lazy='dynamic')
faclilitators = db.relationship('Facilitators', backref='cscommunities', cascade='all, delete-orphan', lazy='dynamic')
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are couple of issues with this code (if we skip the fact that regions, districts, subdistricts, villages and Facilitators are not defined in your snippet):

1. `__tablename = 'cscommunities'` should be `__tablename__ = 'cscommunities'` (notice you're missing second '__')
2. you created `backref='cscommunity'` (relationship) which conflicts with `Agenda.cscommunity` (column). Rename your backref.

I'm getting no errors after fixing both (SQLAlchemy==1.0.4)